# Multi-module spring boot configuration

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to configure a multi-module Spring boot application. The simplest example is:

[image: structure]

pom1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testExample</groupId>
    <artifactId>testExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
    </modules>


</project>
```

pom2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>testExample</artifactId>
        <groupId>testExample</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <start-class>testExamplePackage.RootConfig</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

RootConfig:

```
package testExamplePackage;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RootConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Doing some work...");
    }
}
```

Why am I getting an ERROR starting maven 'clean spring-boot:run'?

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\PROGRAMACION\Projects\TEMP_PROJECTS\testExample "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=57646:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.1 clean spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] testExample
[INFO] module1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testExample 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ testExample ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ testExample >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ testExample <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ testExample ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] testExample ........................................ FAILURE [  0.487 s]
[INFO] module1 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.884 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-25T16:44:47+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project testExample: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It wants mainClass, but this class is already specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mvn clean spring-boot:run` has to be executed from the module that contains the `SpringBootApplication`.
You execute it from the parent pom.

Execute this command from `module1`, it should work.

By the way, this duplicated declaration in `module1` pom.xml is not required as it is already specified by your parent :

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

From the root of the multi-module project, run this:

```
mvn -pl module1 spring-boot:run
```

Now, if you have a `config` folder in the root of your multi-module spring boot project, Spring-boot will also scan that folder for property files  (n addition to src/main/resources), making those properties global to all your modules.